# Diagonal Sudoku

Tags: java, algorithm, sudoku

I implemented a diagonal sudoku.

Diagonals must not have repetitions

My algorithm to check the diagonal was.

1. copy diagonals to arrays `left_x` and `right_x`
2. `for(i) for(j) if(left_x[i]==left_x[j]&&i!=j) return false`
3. `for(i) for(j) if(right_x[i]==right_x[j]&&i!=j) return false`

Is there a better implementation to this in terms of the running time?

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Rather than comparing all pairs of values, just count the number of times each number appears. If any count is larger than 1, it's not valid.